# PLS-00201: ID 'OS_COMMAND.EXEC' must be declared

Tags: oracle, command

I'm trying to grant permissions with dbms_java.grant_permission in the prcedure below.

```
create procedure foo is
begin  
    dbms_java.grant_permission( 'FOOBAR', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', '<<ALL FILES>>', 'execute' ) ;
end foo;
/
```

But I'm getting error:

```
PLS-00201: ID 'OS_COMMAND.EXEC' must be declared
```

What can I do to grant permissions? How should I declare 'OS_COMMAND.EXEC'?

Comment: do you have a package os_command in your database?

Comment: Looks like you need to follow [the instructions (PDF)](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/calling-shell-commands-from-plsql-1-1-129519.pdf)

Comment: I don't have OS_COMMAND.EXEC. The download link mentioned there [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/calling-shell-commands-from-plsql-1-1-129519.pdf) does not exists. Anyone knows where I can download it?